# Hibernate Formula Vs One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a product with many colors.

I used to map it using one-to-many relationship (list) and cont them together with a delimiter  (",")

example: green,red,blue

This is pretty slow when I attempt to retrieve 5000 of records even with JOIN Fetch.

I am wondering should I use formula instead? I know formula will retrieve it using a sub select statement.

o.O

Comment: please post your code so that we can try help you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure all fields (database columns) that you use as primary keys and foreign keys
, in the where clause, and orderby clause have an index in the database.
other than that you should paste your code and sql so more detailed help/advice can be provided